# Please identify this antenna setup

Tags: rf, antenna, wireless

In my neighborhood, this Antenna setup is installed. I think that this is LTE/4G Antenna. What do we call the objects encircled in 3 colors in the picture given below.

I believe that the objects encircled by Blue and Green colors are Antennas and Object encircled in Red color is some control panel having wires going inside it.

Please identify the names of these Antenna.

[image]

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Please don't jump to conclusions. I am very fascinated by Mobile networks technology these days and this Antenna setup came in my locality. So it got me even more curious. That's it. No homework now. That was past.

Comment: Just curiosity, fair enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

The red and green objects appear to be the same things viewed from different angles, and are probably cell phone antennas.

The blue thing is a parabolic microwave antenna.  This is a high bandwidth data link to elsewhere.  In many cases, it's cheaper to use microwave links for data trunks between installations within sight of each other, then to bury copper cable or glass fiber.

Comment: Is Green one a LTE Antenna?

Comment: Possible but does not have to be, the size of an antenna is mainly determined by the frequency band for which it is designed. So an antenna designed for 900 MHz might be used for UMTS, CDMA, LTE or whatever. The shape of the antenna is usually **unrelated** to the type of network. What frequency is used for which network depends on your country/location.